# Passing lines as args to a script

Tags: linux, shell

How do I pass each line from a text file as an argument to a script I have written? So each line is then in itself a single arg to the script each time.

Comment: Be more specific. Why is the perl tag there? Are you reading the lines in perl and then passing to a script, or is the script you are passing to in perl? If the latter, than the perl tag is irrelevant and you need to tell us what language you want to automate the argument passing in.

Comment: The case is the latter. Any language is fine in passing the argument.

Answer (score 3):

```
cat file | xargs --replace script {}
```

I should note that if you want each line of the file to be treated as one argument to your script, add quotes as appropriate to the {}, most likely \"{}\"

Comment: Wrong, {} will be substituted as one argument regardless of contents.  What you want is to change the delimiter from any space (default) to newlines-only, using `-d '\n'` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

No need for `cat`

```
xargs -I {} --arg-file input-file script_file {}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
while read -r line
do
  ./script_i_have_written.sh "$line"
done <"file"
```

but why do that when in your "script_i_have_written.sh", you can parse the text file straight away

```
#!/bin/bash
# script_i_have_written.sh
while read -r line
do 
  echo "do something with $line"
done <"file"
```